# How can I find the dominant orientation of any image?

Tags: java, image-processing, orientation

I have been trying to find some reliable procedure for finding the directional information from image.I am using **DICOM** images and doing the whole procedure in Java.

Are there any techniques in **Java** that can help me?

I want to get a graph of angles from the image depending upon the intensity distribution. General angular plot is not helpful in this case(*radius* and *theta*, from polar conversion).  I believe that the Fourier Transform is a great technique for finding the major direction of image.

But I want to evaluate the result quantitatively, how can I obtain that?

Can someone instruct me how to evaluate/ calculate structure tensor in this case?

Comment: Good luck with that! Determining the "correct" orientation of an arbitrary image is extremely difficult - just ask any museum curator who has hung up abstract art upside down or 90 degrees wrong.

Comment: I am still not able to solve this problem,,,, Please help ... Can somebody suggest me how to learn to operate Java for image processing . Any books or any other source...